# Best practice for getting selected values in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i want to know which way is considered a good practice in this case:
let's say that I have a table of data ($scope.alarms variable) and I need to track selected rows from that table in my application.

```
<script>
    angular.module('app').controller('AlarmController', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.selected_alarms = [];
        var data = [
            {id: 0, name: "data1"},
            {id: 1, name: "data2"},
            {id: 2, name: "data3"},
        ];
        $scope.alarms = data.map((obj) => {
             obj['checked'] = false;
             return obj;
        });
    }]);
</script>
```

is it better to push the selected row data to an array when selecting the row and slicing that row data from the array when unselecting the row like this code:

```
<tr ng-controller="AlarmController" ng-repeat="alarm in alarms">
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="alarm.checked" /></td>
    <td ng-click="control_alarm(alarm)">{{alarm.id}}</td>
    <td ng-click="control_alarm(alarm)">{{alarm.name}}</td>
    <td>
        <div class="col-edit" ng-click="get_selected_alarm(alarm)"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<script>

    $scope.control_alarm = (alarm) => {
        if(alarm.checked){
            $scope.selected_alarms.push(alarm);
        }
        else{
            var index = $scope.selected_alarms.findIndex(obj => obj.id === alarm.id)
            $scope.selected_alarms.splice(index, 1);
        }
    };
    $scope.get_selected_alarm = () => {
        console.log($scope.selected_alarms);
    };
</script>
```

or it is better to manipulate the original data table and change the selected row status and create a loop whenever I want to use the selected data in the data table like that:

```
<tr ng-controller="AlarmController" ng-repeat="alarm in alarms">
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="alarm.checked" /></td>
    <td ng-click="alarm.checked = !alarm.checked">{{alarm.id}}</td>
    <td ng-click="alarm.checked = !alarm.checked">{{alarm.name}}</td>
    <td>
        <div class="col-edit" ng-click="get_selected_alarm(alarm)"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<script>
    $scope.get_selected_alarm = () => {
        var selected_alarms = $scope.alarms.filter(obj => obj.checked);
    };
</script>
```

I want to know which way is better in case of big amount of rows considering angular js performance and clean code perspective.